# How to split mnist dataset into smaller size and adding augmentation to it?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, mnist, data-augmentation

I have this problem of splitting mnist dataset + adding augmentation data. i want to take only total of 22000(including training + test set) data from mnist dataset which is 70000. mnist dataset have 10 label. im only using shear, rotation, width-shift, and heigh-shift for augmetation method.

training set --> 20000(total) --> 20 images + 1980 augmentation images(per label)

test set --> 2000(total) --> 200 images(per label)

i also want to make sure that the class distribution is preserved in the split.

i'm really confused how to split those data. would gladly if anyone can provide the code.

i have tried this code :

```
# Load the MNIST dataset
(x_train_full, y_train_full), (x_test_full, y_test_full) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# Normalize the data
x_train_full = x_train_full / 255.0
x_test_full = x_test_full / 255.0

# Create a data generator for data augmentation
data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(shear_range=0.2, rotation_range=20,
                              width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2)

# Initialize empty lists for the training and test sets
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = [], [], [], []

# Loop through each class/label
for class_n in range(10):
    # Get the indices of the images for this class
    class_indices = np.where(y_train_full == class_n)[0]

    # Select 20 images for training
    train_indices = np.random.choice(class_indices, 20, replace=False)

    # Append the training images and labels to the respective lists
    x_train.append(x_train_full[train_indices])
    y_train.append(y_train_full[train_indices])

    # Select 200 images for test
    test_indices = np.random.choice(class_indices, 200, replace=False)

    # Append the test images and labels to the respective lists
    x_test.append(x_test_full[test_indices])
    y_test.append(y_test_full[test_indices])

    # Generate 100 augmented images for training
    x_augmented = data_gen.flow(x_train_full[train_indices], y_train_full[train_indices], batch_size=100)

    # Append the augmented images and labels to the respective lists
    x_train.append(x_augmented[0])
    y_train.append(x_augmented[1])

# Concatenate the list of images and labels to form the final training and test sets
x_train = np.concatenate(x_train)
y_train = np.concatenate(y_train)
x_test = np.concatenate(x_test)
y_test = np.concatenate(y_test)

print("training set shape: ", x_train.shape)
print("training label shape: ", y_train.shape)
print("test set shape: ", x_test.shape)
print("test label shape: ", y_test.shape)
```

but it keep saying error like this :

```
IndexError: index 15753 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the train and test set. In the loop, you are getting the class_indices from the train set:

```
# Get the indices of the images for this class
class_indices = np.where(y_train_full == class_n)[0]
```

but then you are using these train indices (that might be numbers above 10000!) to address indices in the testset (that has only 10000 samples) some lines further down:

```
# Select 200 images for test
test_indices = np.random.choice(class_indices, 200, replace=False)
```

So, you will need to do the same index-selection for the label in the loop for the test-set and it should work out.